# Clipboard gem working on localhost (OS X), not on dev server (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clipboard

Although I have consulted [the ReadMe](https://github.com/janlelis/clipboard) and ran `sudo apt-get install xsel`, whereas
`xauth is already the newest version (1:1.1-0ubuntu1).`

When processing the controller action:

```
    clipboard = "/activate " + @enc
Rails.logger.info clipboard
    Clipboard.copy(clipboard)
```

the system is logging the clipboard:

```
/activate TguODODMjkNN3Lf=
```

The browser console  when connecting to a Ubuntu develoment server has an http/2 response
but verification of the clipboard on the browser's OS returns  nil,

whereas on localhost (OS X 10.9),  the value is being copied into the clipboard.

What is missing here?

Rails 6.1.4
Ruby 2.6.1

Comment: What on earth is it that you're trying to do? What is "The browser console when connecting to a Ubuntu develoment server" even supposed to mean? Do you mean a browser connected to web server running on the server?

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you want to copy some text to the clients (the browsers) clipboard? This is'nt even remotely what you want for this - rather it would just copy something into the servers own clipboard (which is strange in itself as clipboards are really just a UI thing for us stupid humans). What you want is probably to use [the JavasScript clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) on the browser.

Comment: You are correct.  I misread the documentation `Clipboard.copy - Copies a string to system clipboard` intepreting it as being applicable to the client's system.  And yes, meanwhile I found the JS API and its documentation.